# Using EXCEPT before WITH RECURSIVE in SQLite 3

Tags: sqlite, except

Is there anyway to do this? I'm trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT x
FROM table
EXCEPT
WITH RECURSIVE ...();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `WITH` goes first in a query. You can use this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE ct AS (...)
SELECT x
FROM table
EXCEPT
SELECT y
FROM ct ;
```

For the record, CTEs can be (in standard SQL) inside subqueries but not many DBMS have implemented this syntax:

```
SELECT x
FROM table
EXCEPT
SELECT y
FROM 
  ( WITH RECURSIVE ct AS (...)
    SELECT y
    FROM ct 
  ) AS c ;
```

or this simpler one:

```
SELECT x
FROM table
EXCEPT
( WITH RECURSIVE ct AS (...)
  SELECT y
  FROM ct 
) ;
```

Comment: SQLite *does* support CTEs in subqueries. But neither in standard SQL nor in SQLite are you allowed to use subqueries directly in compound queries.

Comment: @CL. what do you mean "you are not allowed to use subqueries directly"?

Comment: @CL.: neither of those examples uses a "sub-query". Those are derived tables - which is something different then a sub-query. Most importantly a derived table can be used anywhere a regular table can be used. All three queries are perfectly valid by the SQL standard (apart from the missing alias for the derived table if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ With `A EXCEPT B`, both `A` and `B` must be queries, not subqueries.

Comment: CL. I don't understand what you mean with subquery then. Both `(select * from t) except (select * from t);` and `select * from t except select * from t;` are valid queries, as far as I know.

Comment: `SELECT ...`, not `(SELECT ...)`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name all the 3 I have in my answer run fine in Postgres.

Comment: @CL Skimming the SQL-99 standard (old, but still relevant), non-join query expression (which defines UNION/EXCEPT) can contain parenthesized queries as either operand: non-join query expression can be composed of non-join query primary containing *left-paren non-join query expression right-paren* then work back down from non-join query expression to query specification via non-join query term. Looks like valid standard SQL to me (not to mention it works happily in many engines which is probably a more useful yardstick ;)

Comment: SQLite does not claim anything newer than SQL-92, but that part uses the same grammar. Okay, I take everything back and claim the opposite.